# IF statement not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

**Before I start I am learning PHP/Mysql, so I am trying to learn and understand all that before I move onto mysqli and researching correct security steps, so I am aware this code will have holes int it.**

Basically I am implementing a member group system and I am trying to work out the coding so that..

IF a member is in the group, show "group member"
IF a member isn't in the group, "join group"
IF a member has already requested a join, but accepted is still = 0(pending) show "invite pending".

Here is my code so far, it's inside an include.

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['gid'];
$gruser = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$group = "SELECT * FROM `disc_users` WHERE user_id='$gruser' AND group_id='$id'";
$gres = mysql_query($group);

if ($gres == 0) { ?>
<input type="button" class="sub-button" value="Join Group">
<? 
} 
if ($gres == 1) { ?>
<input type="button" class="sub-button" value="Group Member">
<? } ?>
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, it's not displaying errors, but I am getting white space, no buttons, I even added "echo" in front of $group and it's getting the values correctly.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does `var_dump($gres)` output?

Comment: See the [return value of `mysql_query`](http://dk1.php.net/mysql_query#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues). In other words, if `$gres` is not `0` or `1` then it has to be *something else*. It is just simple logic reasoning.

Comment: Lets look at the query. You are saying - select everything from the table that has the users' id AND their group id matches the current group. If they are not a member of the group then there shouldn't be any data returned.

Answer (score 0):

You cant simply compare mysql_query result you have to use mysql_fetch_row etc but in your case may be like this:

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET['gid'];
    $gruser = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $group = "SELECT * FROM `disc_users` WHERE user_id='$gruser' AND group_id='$id'";
    $gres = mysql_query($group);

    if (mysql_num_rows($gres) < 0) { ?>
    <input type="button" class="sub-button" value="Join Group">
    <? 
    } 
    else{ ?>
    <input type="button" class="sub-button" value="Group Member">
    <? } ?>
```